# Date not sorting properly using SQL over partition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's my query:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT ComputerName
    ,      LastUpdate
    ,      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ComputerName ORDER BY LastUpdate ASC) CN
    FROM My_Table
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE CN > 0 and ComputerName = '4408Q12'
```

This is the result:

```
<pre>
   ComputerName     LastUpdate
      4408Q12   Feb 10 2015  3:45PM
      4408Q12   Feb 11 2015  6:10PM
      4408Q12   Jan 27 2015  2:09PM
      4408Q12   Jan 28 2015  1:10PM
</pre>
```

Why is Feb 10 coming up before Feb 11? Even DESC it sorts wrong,
 always second, not first. When I use CN > 1 Feb 10 is left. I need to
 most recent date as a result. What the heck am I missing here?

Comment: Looks like it's creating the dates as "strings" and sorting them alphabetically. Are the dates actual DATE data types in the SQL server?

Comment: `order by... asc`? Why shouldn't it come first? You're sorting strings, not dates.

Comment: You're not doing anything with your row-number. You're building it inside your CTE, and then saying "where its greater than zero" (which is everything), but then you neither select it out, or sort by it.

Comment: No, they are string. Should I cast them as date first?

Comment: order in the inside subquery is not guaranteed in the super query.

Comment: I am showing all rows to show all data. I will change CN to 1 to use the query.

Comment: Why on earth are you storing dates as a string? There is a perfectly good data type for storing dates and times. I'd suggest reading  [Bad habits to Kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type), and also [Bad habits to Kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Comment: strings are ordered lexicographically, as in a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a CTE that gives you the order, but *you're not ordering the results*.  Add

```
ORDER BY CN
```

to your outer query.

but at that point your query is equivalent to

```
SELECT ComputerName
,      LastUpdate
FROM My_Table
WHERE ComputerName = '4408Q12'
ORDER BY LastUpdate ASC
```

And yes, you could convert the strings to dates in the ORDER BY clause.

Side note:  `CN` will *never* be 0.

Comment: Thank you D. I needed to CAST LastUpdate to DATE and it worked fine. I am going to change CN > 1 to return the oldest updates. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Order by` in last `select` query else order won't be guarenteed

```
    ;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT ComputerName
    ,      LastUpdate
    ,      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ComputerName ORDER BY cast(LastUpdate as date) ASC) CN
    FROM My_Table
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE CN > 0 and ComputerName = '4408Q12'
ORDER BY cast(LastUpdate as date)
```